# How to send a post request with array of strings in the body

Tags: c#, .net, webrequest

I'm trying to send and http post request in a console app with an array if string in the body, but its not working.

Here is the code:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(Url);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";
string[] firstData = { "89", "354", "AF001" };
StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
requestWriter.Write(firstData);
requestWriter.Close();

string[] secondData = { "8911", "354", "01" };;
StreamWriter requestWriter2 = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
requestWriter2.Write(secondData);
requestWriter2.Close();
```

Comment: What does *it's not working* mean? What isn't working.

Comment: not sending the request and throwing an exception, hold on Ill write the exception

Comment: it throws this exeption on StreamWriter requestWriter2 = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
System.ArgumentException : {"Stream was not writable."}

Answer (score 1):

You can't re-use the same `WebRequest` stream twice, which you're doing when calling `request.GetRequestStream` on both `StreamWriter` instantiations. That's why it's throwing the exception. I'm not sure why you're getting the request stream twice, each time to a different `StreamWriter`. You can simply combine them to one:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(Url);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";

using (StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
{
    string[] firstData = { "89", "354", "AF001" };
    requestWriter.Write(firstData);

    string[] secondData = { "8911", "354", "01" }; ;
    requestWriter.Write(secondData);
}
```

As a side note, you can greatly reduce the verbosiness of your code using `WebClient`:

```
using (var webClient = new WebClient())
{
    webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
    webClient.UploadData(Url, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(firstData));
    webClient.UploadData(Url, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secondData));
}
```

Comment: the Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(firstData) is char[] and not string[]

Comment: the first one stopped throwing exception, but still doesnt seems to be sending a request not sure...

Comment: are you sure thats the right way to send an array of strings? That was my main question, how to send an array of string using WebRequest

Comment: this method didnt send two requests

Comment: @EnderCode You can easily concat both arrays and send them as one.

Comment: I need to send 2 requests, dont want to concatenate

Comment: @EnderCode Two separate requests?

Comment: yes. I think I should create two different WebRequest

Comment: @EnderCode Or simply use `UploadData` twice (Edited my code).

Comment: I didnt use the uploaddata. I dont want to send a byte[] array.

Answer (score 1):

I changed `string[]` to `var` and it worked:

```
 WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(apiUrl);
 request.Method = "POST";
 request.ContentType = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";

 data = "[ \"89\", \"354\", \"AF001\" ]";

 StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());

 requestWriter.Write(data);

 requestWriter.Close();



  WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
  Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);

  response.Close();

  request = WebRequest.Create(url);
  request.Method = "POST";
  request.ContentType = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";


   StreamWriter requestWriter2 = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream())

   var data2 = ""[ \"55\", \"3524\", \"b01\" ]";

   requestWriter2.Write(data2);
   requestWriter2.Close();

   WebResponse response2 = request.GetResponse()
   Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response2).StatusDescription);
```

created new WebResponse and StreamWriter for the second request